# java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01424: missing or illegal character following the escape character

Tags: java, oracle

I've installed Oracle Express 11g and try to read database tables from my java application using ojdbc6. However, I get exception on the following statement:

```
connection.getMetaData().getColumns(null, null, table, null);
```

the full stack trace of the exception is:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01424: missing or illegal character following the escape character

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1010)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1185)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3620)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDatabaseMetaData.getColumnsWithWildcards(OracleDatabaseMetaData.java:331)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDatabaseMetaData.getColumns(OracleDatabaseMetaData.java:125)
at org.nicholding.nicat.view.wizard.ImportTablePage.getNumberOfColumns(ImportTablePage.java:316)
at org.nicholding.nicat.view.wizard.ImportTablePage$3.getText(ImportTablePage.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnLabelProvider.update(ColumnLabelProvider.java:36)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:152)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTableViewer.java:399)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:485)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable$1.run(SafeRunnable.java:128)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2167)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.createItem(AbstractTableViewer.java:277)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefreshAll(AbstractTableViewer.java:757)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:649)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:636)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer$2.run(AbstractTableViewer.java:592)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1443)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1404)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTableViewer.java:590)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:280)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1690)
at org.nicholding.nicat.view.wizard.ImportTablePage.setVisible(ImportTablePage.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1259)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.access$4(WizardDialog.java:1238)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$8.run(WizardDialog.java:1227)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1225)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:915)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at org.nicholding.nicat.view.wizard.NICATWizard.open(NICATWizard.java:70)
at org.nicholding.nicat.controller.Controller.actionMenuFileImportData(Controller.java:98)
at org.nicholding.nicat.view.MainWindow$ImportDataListener.widgetSelected(MainWindow.java:250)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.nicholding.nicat.Main.main(Main.java:70)
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What value does table have?, btw, acordingly doc, columnname(last parameter) cannot be null https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: use the JDBC driver that matches with your oracle version

Comment: I do use the matching version

Comment: Can you post a little more code prior to that statement?  To see how you're setting up your connection object.

Comment: do we have any solution?, and this is raised for : table SYS_NT0q/QcEraQaatSL7h+M1a2A==

Answer (score 3):

This is because your table name contains this character: `'/'`, try to escape tables whoes name contains this.